# how to extract a whole number in Thymeleaf?

Tags: thymeleaf

I do not find the way to get the whole part of a decimal number in Thymeleaf.

For example: 2,54 will be 2, or 234,01 will be 234.

## numbers.formatInteger

rounds the number up or down, but 2,54 gets to 3 instead of 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't find a simple way to do this with the built in thymeleaf objects/methods, but this will work (even if it's a little painful).

Controller

```
@GetMapping
public String page(Map<String, Object> model) {
    .
    .
    DecimalFormat f = new DecimalFormat("#");
    f.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.FLOOR);
    model.put("format", f);
    .
    .
}
```

Page

```
<th:block th:with="n=${2.54}">
    <!-- outputs 2 -->
    <span th:text="${format.format(n)}" />
</th:block>
```

Comment: It works, but I do not understand why you have to involve the Controller into something that is for the presentation layer. Why format(n) alone does not work. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Metroids is it still same solution  or there is now something thymeleaf  can do?